# Why doesn't this simple Lua coroutine work?

Tags: multithreading, lua, coroutine

I have a very simple little piece of Lua code, which I wrote while teaching myself how coroutines work.

I was fine until I got to coroutine.wrap, the [spec](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-coroutine.wrap) states:

> coroutine.wrap (f)
>
> Creates a new coroutine, with body f.
>   f must be a Lua function. Returns a
>   function that resumes the coroutine
>   each time it is called. Any arguments
>   passed to the function behave as the
>   extra arguments to resume. Returns the
>   same values returned by resume, except
>   the first boolean. In case of error,
>   propagates the error.

However this code:

```
Enumeration = {}

Enumeration.Create = function(generator)
    return coroutine.wrap(generator, coroutine.yield)
end

local function TestEnumerator(yield)
    yield(1) --ERROR HERE
    yield(2)
    yield(3)
end

local enumerator = Enumeration.Create(TestEnumerator)
local first = enumerator()
local second = enumerator()
local third = enumerator()

print (first, second, third)
```

Complains that yield is nil (on the line I have marked above). As I understand it, yield should be the second argument passed into coroutine.wrap, so where am I going wrong?

Really obvious solution, thanks to the answer below

```
Enumeration.Create = function(generator)
    local iter = coroutine.wrap(generator, coroutine.yield)
    return function()
        return iter(coroutine.yield)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how `coroutine.wrap` works. You have to pass `coroutine.yield` in the first call to `enumerator`.

Comment: Bah, once you said that it becamse so obvious I was simply misreading the documentation.

Comment: To get a more uniform behaviour you need cooperation of the wrapped functions but if they yield as soon as they start then Create can wrap and call it once to set yield.